# URL loses its markup in javascript framework (BotUI)

Tags: javascript, bots, markup

I'm trying to use the BotUI javascript framework (https://github.com/botui/botui) for my website.

I've got a problem with using URLs, and I think it has to do with the order of the messages. That is, it seems that the URL markup gets removed from a message when another message is shown afterwards.

In other words, if a message contains an URL, and it is the last message shown, then there is no problem (see example 1). But if this message is shown prior to other messages, it loses its URL markup (see example 2).

Example 1 (message maintains its URL)

```
botui.message.bot( {
  content: 'Hi there!'

}).then(function () {
  return botui.message.bot( {
    content: 'Google [google](http://google.com)'
  });
});
```

Example 2 (message loses its URL markup)

```
botui.message.bot( {
  content: 'Google [google](http://google.com)'

}).then(function () {
  return botui.message.bot( {
    content: 'Hi there'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the issue as well. It seems that latest version of Vue.js is causing problem. Switching to the version v2.0.5 solved the issue for me.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vue/2.0.5

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect anymore that someone would answer my question. But you were right; switching to v2.0.5 worked!